# upgrade new version app in swift without App Store

Tags: ios

I need to upload a new version of iOS  application in to my web server .
but i can't know how can ??

and how can create code for download new version ?

can you help me ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want AdHoc distribution using over-the-air delivery.  See this:

http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/over-the-air-ios-provisioning-and-distribution/

Essentially

1. Make an AdHoc build with an ad hoc distribution profile
2. Create the OTA plist and icons
3. Put them all on an HTTPS server
4. Construct an `itms-services://` link to the plist (which, in turn, refers to the app and icons)